# How should I access other modules within a module?

Tags: module, lua

I'm struggling with the "global" aspect of functions as it relates to modules.  Maybe someone here could tell me if this example would work, explain why  and then tell me the right way to do it.

If I have two modules:

f1.lua

```
local mod = T{}
function mod.print_msg(msg)
    print(msg)
end
return mod
```

f2.lua

```
local mod = T{}
function mod.print_hello()
    msgmod.print_msg('Hello')
end
return mod
```

and both are called in a "main" file

```
msgmod = assert(loadfile(file_path .. 'f1.lua'))()
himod = assert(loadfile(file_path .. 'f2.lua'))()
himod.print_hello()
```

Would print_hello still work if called from f2 or would I need to loadfile() f1.lua in f2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would work if called after the `msgmod = ...` has been executed (in *any* file), but not before. This is a confusing situation due to the usage of globals.

Typically, you do not want to use globals like this in modules. You should handle dependencies using `require` just as you would `#include` them in C++. So, f2.lua, which wants to use `print_msg` defined in f1.lua, might look like this:

```
local f1 = require('f1')
local mod = T{}
function mod.print_hello()
    f1.print_msg('Hello')
end
return mod
```

You should also use `require` in your main file (and get in the habit of making everything local):

```
local msgmod = require('f1')
local himod = require('f2')
himod.print_hello()
```

Note that we could have omitted the first line, since we aren't actually using f1 in main, and f2 will require it automatically when we require f2. Unlike `loadfile`, `require` automatically caches loaded modules such that they are loaded only once. Again, `require` is almost always what you want to use.

The general pattern for writing modules is to require all dependency modules into locals, then use them as you like to implement your module functions:

```
local dep1 = require('dep1')
local dep2 = require('dep2')
...
local mod = {}
function mod.foo ()
  return dep1.bar(dep2.bazz())
end
return mod
```